# Helper does not function properly for Custom Lang.php core in Codeigniter v2.x.x

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Let say the input of my custom language was:

```
$lang['number.you.got'] = 'Number you got was %1, %2 and %3';
```

I've modified the **Lang.php** in **/system/core/** codeigniter 2 folder. Here is the code:

```
function line($line = '')
{
    //get the arguments passed to the function
            $args = func_get_args();

            //count the number of arguments
            $c = count($args);

            //if one or more arguments, perform the necessary processing
            if ($c)
            {
                //first argument should be the actual language line key
                //so remove it from the array (pop from front)
                $line = array_shift($args);

                //check to make sure the key is valid and load the line
                $line = ($line == '' OR ! isset($this->language[$line])) ? FALSE : $this->language[$line];

                // Because killer robots like unicorns!
                if ($line === FALSE)
                {
                        log_message('error', 'Could not find the language line "'.$line.'"');
                }

                //if the line exists and more function arguments remain
                //perform wildcard replacements
                if ($line && $args)
                {
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach ($args as $arg)
                    {
                        $line = preg_replace('/\%'.$i.'/', $arg, $line);
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //if no arguments given, no language line available
                $line = false;
            }

            return $line;

}
```

The modified codes above is to implement the language in the website, let say:

```
$this->lang->line('number.you.got','number1','number2','number3');
```

and the output will be

```
Number you got was number1, number2 and number3
```

Now, I used `language_helper` in **codeigniter v2**

```
function lang($line)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $line = $CI->lang->line($line);
    $line = '<label>'.$line."</label>";
    return $line;
}
```

But the result was not the same as I got before.

My expected result that if I can easily use helper `lang('number.you.got','number1','number2','number3')`...

Anybody can help me?

Comment: What was your (wrong) result?

Comment: The result become `Number you got was %1, %2 and %3` instead of  `Number you got was number1, number2 and number3`

Comment: Have you tested that your custom function/method is called at all?

Comment: Yes I do, it works fine...my problems just the helper does not perform as `$this->lang->line()`

Comment: In your helper sample you don't provide any additional arguments than line to the Lang object.

Comment: So, how I can do that?